# Driver not always visible in the graph editor?

Tags: drivers, layers

I have encountered a problem where my driver would not show in the graph editor while viewing Layer 1 and layer 11. I discovered that moving the wheels in question would show the driver in the graph editor in layer 3? Although the driver worked in the said layers but did not show.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) We like to keep to one question per post here, to keep things organized and on-topic. If you have multiple distinct questions, you are more than welcome to create multiple posts.

Comment: There [isn't a built-in way to upload files at the moment](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/297/599), but you can use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). To request clarifications etc, it's preferred to use [*comments*](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). *Edits* are for clarifying or adding info to your post.

Comment: Ok thx for the info. Will comment when I have succeeded.

Comment: Managed to upload it. Just using materials to see what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

You have *Show only selected* enabled in the graph editor:

[image]

While this setting is enabled, only drivers and fcurves belonging to selected objects will be shown.

Comment: Ok thx, but it still doesn't show when I untick it as in pic. Doesn't show in f-curve either even tho I have the selected item highlighted. http://i.stack.imgur.com/kyROy.jpg

Comment: @PeteL900 Hm.. Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Answer (score 2):

I had a pretty similar problem as well. What gandalf3 wrote is definitely correct.
I just want to add the following:

Instead of disabling the *Selected Only* button (little Cursor Icon) you could as well enable the *Invisible Objects* button next to it (Ghost Icon).

Other than flooding your list of drivers shown on the right with all existing ones, you still only see, what you want to see. This is especially helpful when applying drivers to empties, which might not show up, if you have this button disabled.